# How would I say "change the laundry"?

Tags: translation, phrase, expressions

I use the phrase "change the laundry" to mean "move the laundry from the washing machine to the dryer." I would like to know how to say this in Chinese.

I checked Pleco, and found 晒衫, but that means to hang clothes up to dry, which is a little different.

I checked Google translate, and got 换衣服, but I assume that would be understood as "change one's clothes".

And of course, I could always say something like, 把衣服从洗衣机拿出来放在干衣里, but I'd like to know if there is something more concise.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker but a quick search suggests that the English phrase is ... idiosyncratic ;-).

Comment: That's funny. I am a native speaker and my family has been saying that my whole life. Then again, my family is fairly idiosyncratic in general :)

Comment: My wife's family says it too, so maybe it's a regional phrase

Comment: Interesting! Perhaps you can find some information about that?

Comment: Perhaps someone can go to Stack Exchange English language site and ask if "change the laundry" is indeed a common, acceptable usage or idiosyncratic. Just a thought.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

把衣服从洗衣机拿出来放在干衣**机**里 or 把衣服拿出来烘干 or 把衣服烘干 is the correct answer.

烘 means heat up objects with hot/warm air

```
我觉得国内绝大多数家庭里都不用干衣机吧，通常都是晾干或者晒干，
至少我家是不用干衣机的（虽然有洗干一体机）
所以没有对应 change the laundry 的说法好像也很正常。
```

Answer (score 3):

@Virgil Ming: neither is a dishwasher!!

'change the laundry' is somewhat idiomatic!

Stick the wet washing in the dryer please.
请吧洗好的衣服放进烘干机。

Answer (score 1):

There really isn’t such a dedicated concise phrase. Dryer hasn’t been a thing in common household of China.

Answer (score 1):

"change the laundry" isn't proper English either. You probably mean "put the laundry in the dryer".